# How to set up Apache api witohut virtual host?

Tags: asp.net, apache, proxy, blazor, hosting

I have a NET CORE site (BLAZOR WASP hosted NET CORE), that has an api and following [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-6.0)  it works fine but...

Since this website is not alone in the server and the virtual host needs to be set listening on port 8080 (80 breaks the other websites since proxy is working on the DocumentRoot) and is a bit annoying to have all websites (no NET CORE) in port 80 and then one single site that has to show the port in the URL. [www.example.com:8080/websiteRoot](http://www.example.com:8080/websiteRoot).

Simplified question: How to set up Net Core site, alongside static blazor sites and not break the static sites with the reverse proxy.

**Note**:
`/var/www/websitefolder/wwwroot` contains the index, and the api call `www.example.com/api/Something` goes through `ErrorDocument 404 /wwwroot/index.html`, so apache finds the index in `www.example.com/` and the blazor app handles `/api/Something`

**CODE:**

Virtual Host

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/websitefolder"
    ServerName www.example.com

     ProxyPreserveHost On
     ProxyPass / http://localhost:5001/
     ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5001/
     RequestHeader set Connection "keep-alive"
    # Other directives here


<Directory /var/www/websitefolder>
        ErrorDocument 404 /wwwroot/index.html
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Kestrel service

```
[Unit]
Description=My .NET Core Website running on Ubuntu
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/websitefolder
ExecStart=/var/www/websitefolder/app.Server --urls=http://localhost:5001/
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
TimeoutStopSec=90
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-mycoreapp
User=root
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I tried this (code below) and the index can't be fetched prooperly, guess because of     `DocumentRoot "/var/www/websitefolder"` missing.

```
<Location /var/www/websitefolder>
     ProxyPreserveHost On
     ProxyPass http://localhost:5001/
     ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:5001/
     RequestHeader set Connection "keep-alive"
</Location>
```

Comment: You need something to differentiate between your VirtualHosts.  Either port (like 8080 here), or domain name.  Are all your site on the same domain name?  OR you could setup the proxy on a particular URL, so you would have example.com/blazor doing the proxy and example.com/ANYTHING-ELSE not proxy.  But something as to differ for Apache to know.

Comment: Ex https://serverfault.com/questions/130694/how-can-i-redirect-urls-using-the-proxy-module-in-apache, and many others if you search.

Comment: "OR you could setup the proxy on a particular URL" looks like what i've been looking for, I will look up how to do that. Thank you.